# ¿por qué aparecen problemas con los paréntesis de un for?

Tags: javascript

alguien me puede ayudar?

estoy haciendo este for:

```
for (i=0, i<datos.length, i++){
    if(datos[i] == "number"){
        var suma = suma + datos[i];
        console.log(suma);
    }
};
```

pero en la consola me

Comment: `for (i=0;  i<datos.length; i++){` debes utilizar punto y coma `;` estas usando coma `,`

Comment: Exactamente como dice @DuvalAD los separadores del `for` deben ser `;` y no solo `,`. Saludos.

Comment: Agrega como estas definiendo la variable datos, porque estas igualando a number

Comment: A todo programador nuevo en JS siempre le recomiendo esto: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/ es importante usar los `===` en lugar de solo 2 `==`. Los motivos están explicados dentro del enlace

Answer (score 2):

El bucle `for` tiene 3 partes

```
for (inicialización; condición; actualización) { 
//sentencias a ejecutar en cada iteración 
}
```

donde cada parte se debe separar con **`;` `(punto y coma)`**, que esto indica una pausa,
entonces tu error esta en que estas intentado separar las partes del `for` con `,` `(coma)` entonces aplicando lo que comente tu `for` debería quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
for (i=0; i<datos.length; i++){
   if(datos[i] == "number"){
      var suma = suma + datos[i];
      console.log(suma);
   }
};
```

> Aclarando que estoy dejando a un lado de como estés utilizando la variable `datos`, el error que encuentro es con los separadores del `for`, en caso de tener problemas con esa parte, tendrías que agregar como lo estas definiendo.